# Switching from front and back images

Tags: javascript, canvas

Im working on a target practice game, its only in the beginning stages right now but im trying to work in the target, however when I put the target image in it became blinked to the front and behind of the 'crosshairs' image instead of staying in the back. It takes a some time before it actually starts blinking forward and backward This is my code:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown, false)
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp, false)
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
var imagename = 'image name'
var secondImageName = 'second image'
//presets Pressed variables to false
var WPressed = false;
var SPressed = false;
var DPressed = false;
var APressed = false;


//If the key is pressed it will check if it is one of the wasd keys and set one of the Pressed values to true
function keyDown(event) {
  console.log('functiondown');
  if (event.keyCode == 83) { //w key
    console.log('pressed');
    WPressed = true
  } else if (event.keyCode == 87) { //s key
    SPressed = true
  } else if (event.keyCode == 65) { //a key
    APressed = true
  } else if (event.keyCode == 68) { //d key
    DPressed = true
  }
}
//If the key is not pressed it will check if it is one of the wasd keys and set one of the Pressed values to false
function keyUp(e) {
  console.log('functionup');
  if (e.keyCode == 83) { //w key
    console.log('not');
    WPressed = false
  } else if (e.keyCode == 87) { //s key
    SPressed = false
  } else if (e.keyCode == 65) { //a key
    APressed = false
  } else if (e.keyCode == 68) { //d key
    DPressed = false
  }
}


var Lx = 20
var Ly = 20
var STx = 50
var STy = 50
laser = new Image();
stilltarget = new Image();
stilltarget.src = 'Target.png';
stilltarget.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(stilltarget, STx, STy);
}

function draw2() {
  stilltarget = new Image();
  stilltarget.src = 'Target.png';
  stilltarget.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(stilltarget, STx, STy);
  }
  setTimeout(function() {}, 190);
}
setInterval(draw2, 90)


function draw() {
  if (WPressed == true) {
    Ly += 10
    console.log('Change')
  } else if (SPressed == true) {
    Ly -= 10
  } else if (DPressed == true) {
    Lx += 10
  } else if (APressed == true) {
    Lx -= 10
  }
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  laser.src = 'crosshairs.png';
  laser.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(laser, Lx, Ly);
  }
  setTimeout(function() {}, 190);
}
setInterval(draw, 90)
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  margin 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='myCanvas' width=1750 height=1000></canvas>
<h1>Target Practice</h1>
<h2>Episode 1</h2>
```

Comment: Why are you drawing in two different intervals that aren't aligned?  Combine your rendering into a single function and z-order what draws first, back to front.  You're also reloading your image every loop which is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems that I can see:

1. You are reloading your images every loop
2. You have too many loops

I would suggest loading all your images up front an then starting your game loop after they have loaded.  You do something different after you have your game actually rendering.

Try something like the following:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown, false)
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp, false)
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
var imagename = 'image name'
var secondImageName = 'second image'
//presets Pressed variables to false
var WPressed = false;
var SPressed = false;
var DPressed = false;
var APressed = false;


//If the key is pressed it will check if it is one of the wasd keys and set one of the Pressed values to true
function keyDown(event) {
    console.log('functiondown');
    if (event.keyCode == 83) { //w key
        console.log('pressed');
        WPressed = true
    } else if (event.keyCode == 87) { //s key
        SPressed = true
    } else if (event.keyCode == 65) { //a key
        APressed = true
    } else if (event.keyCode == 68) { //d key
        DPressed = true
    }
}
//If the key is not pressed it will check if it is one of the wasd keys and set one of the Pressed values to false
function keyUp(e) {
    console.log('functionup');
    if (e.keyCode == 83) { //w key
        console.log('not');
        WPressed = false
    } else if (e.keyCode == 87) { //s key
        SPressed = false
    } else if (e.keyCode == 65) { //a key
        APressed = false
    } else if (e.keyCode == 68) { //d key
        DPressed = false
    }
}

var Lx = 20
var Ly = 20
var STx = 50
var STy = 50

function loadImage(src) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = src;
        img.addEventListener("load", function() {
            resolve(img);
        });
        img.addEventListener("error", function() {
            reject("Failed to load " + src);
        });
    });
}

var targetImg,
    crosshairImg;

function draw() {
    if (WPressed == true) {
        Ly += 10
        console.log('Change')
    } else if (SPressed == true) {
        Ly -= 10
    } else if (DPressed == true) {
        Lx += 10
    } else if (APressed == true) {
        Lx -= 10
    }

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    context.drawImage(targetImg, STx, STy);
    context.drawImage(crosshairImg, Lx, Ly);
}

Promise.all([
    loadImage("Target.png"),
    loadImage("crosshairs.png")
]).then(function(imgs) {
    targetImg = imgs[0];
    crosshairImg = imgs[1];
    setInterval(draw, 100);
});
```

The core of this is the `loadImage` function that will return a Promise that will encapsulate waiting for an image to load:

```
function loadImage(src) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = src;
        img.addEventListener("load", function() {
            resolve(img);
        });
        img.addEventListener("error", function() {
            reject("Failed to load " + src);
        });
    });
}
```

Also, as I said, you have 3 loops when you probably only need one and you are making a new loop every time you reload your image.

Take a look at the following that uses the code above as well as base64 encoded placeholder images:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown, false)
document.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp, false)
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
var imagename = 'image name'
var secondImageName = 'second image'
//presets Pressed variables to false
var WPressed = false;
var SPressed = false;
var DPressed = false;
var APressed = false;


//If the key is pressed it will check if it is one of the wasd keys and set one of the Pressed values to true
function keyDown(event) {
  console.log('functiondown');
  if (event.keyCode == 83) { //w key
    console.log('pressed');
    WPressed = true
  } else if (event.keyCode == 87) { //s key
    SPressed = true
  } else if (event.keyCode == 65) { //a key
    APressed = true
  } else if (event.keyCode == 68) { //d key
    DPressed = true
  }
}
//If the key is not pressed it will check if it is one of the wasd keys and set one of the Pressed values to false
function keyUp(e) {
  console.log('functionup');
  if (e.keyCode == 83) { //w key
    console.log('not');
    WPressed = false
  } else if (e.keyCode == 87) { //s key
    SPressed = false
  } else if (e.keyCode == 65) { //a key
    APressed = false
  } else if (e.keyCode == 68) { //d key
    DPressed = false
  }
}

var Lx = 20
var Ly = 20
var STx = 50
var STy = 50

function loadImage(src) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    img.addEventListener("load", function() {
      resolve(img);
    });
    img.addEventListener("error", function() {
      reject("Failed to load " + src);
    });
  });
}

var targetImg,
  crosshairImg;

function draw() {
  if (WPressed == true) {
    Ly += 10
    console.log('Change')
  } else if (SPressed == true) {
    Ly -= 10
  } else if (DPressed == true) {
    Lx += 10
  } else if (APressed == true) {
    Lx -= 10
  }

  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  context.drawImage(targetImg, STx, STy);
  context.drawImage(crosshairImg, Lx, Ly);
}

Promise.all([
  loadImage("data:image/png;base64,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"),
  loadImage("data:image/png;base64,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")
]).then(function(imgs) {
  targetImg = imgs[0];
  crosshairImg = imgs[1];
  setInterval(draw, 100);
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  margin 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='myCanvas' width=1750 height=1000></canvas>
<h1>Target Practice</h1>
<h2>Episode 1</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly and it's so much smoother! You're a god!